# ROS Answers SE migration: ros mapping

Tags: quadcopter, navigation, lidar, mapping, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi im using an asctec quadrotor, and i would like to map the environment, the only odometry data that i can provide is the velocity, can someone please suggest which form of mapping is the most suitable ?
im using a hokuyo urg lidar as my sensor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11945/ros-mapping/) by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two open source options available that I know of and that should work 'out of the box' after setup of the system (robot model, tf frames etc.) :

The mapping system developed within the CityFlyer project from CCNY uses a scanmatching approach for generating a odometry estimate and feeds this to gmapping. Described [here](http://robolab.cse.unsw.edu.au/conferences/ICRA-2011/data/papers/1749.pdf).

[hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) uses fast scan alignment at 40Hz directly and does not require odometry data. Both available tutorials should help with robot setup. Described in [this paper](http://www.sim.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/publ/download/2011_SSRR_KohlbrecherMeyerStrykKlingauf_Flexible_SLAM_System.pdf). (Note I'm involved here, shameless plug and all :) )

Both approaches have been tested successfully with datasets recorded on quadrotors.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-02-02**:
using the wiki syntax instead of raw HTML seems to work in both the preview and final result..

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-11-16**:
Hm, in the "preview" section when editing the message, the above mess of links looks clean and correct as intended. Any ideas on what's wrong?

**Comment by [Amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/4583/amarante/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi, the first link about the CityFlyer project is not working. Is this one? http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5980460   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mapping using only a 2D range sensor on a 6DOF vehicle is quite tricky. If you can keep the altitude fairly fixed (or are willing to pretend that the world is uniform along the z-axis, which is fairly true above desk height), you can probably use gmapping. If your quadrotor has an accelerometer, you can use that to figure out which way "up" is, and then project the 2D scan onto the X-Y plane, and pass it to gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yea im trying to use hector mapping, but im having problems with the bag file. I can get the map data with the sample bag files put up but cant get anything from the bagfiles i create. im subscribing to /scan /tf and /asctec/imucalcdata , the tf frames are just basic ones that just describe the location of the lidar with respect to the center of gravity of the quadrotor. can u please tell me if im missing anything
im using the hokuyo urg 04lx

---

Originally posted by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) with karma: 53 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-11-16**:
Can you post the tf frame names? Or better yet, upload the bag file somewhere?